# How do you get the LOGBOOK information from the current heading at point?

Tags: org-mode

Given a TODO that looks like this:

```
*** DONE put into spacemacs file
    CLOSED: [2018-08-04 Sat 21:18]
   :LOGBOOK:
    CLOCK: [2018-08-04 Sat 21:16]--[2018-08-04 Sat 12:18] =>  0:02
   :END:
```

What function will get me the parts in `CLOCK: [2018-08-04 Sat 21:16]--[2018-08-04 Sat 12:18] =>  0:02`?

Preferably it would be in plist format like the closed timestamp org-element-at-point gives back of:

`(timestamp (:type inactive :raw-value "[2018-08-04 Sat 21:18]" :year-start 2018 :month-start 8 :day-start 4 :hour-start 21 :minute-start 18 :year-end 2018 :month-end 8 :day-end 4 :hour-end 21 :minute-end 18 :begin 46 :end 68 :post-blank 0)`

Note org-element-at-point doesn't give back logbook information:

```
(headline (:raw-value "put into spacemacs file" :begin 1 :end 157 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 34 :contents-end 157 :level 3 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword #("DONE" 0 4 (fontified t face org-done)) :todo-type done :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 1 :closed (timestamp (:type inactive :raw-value "[2018-08-04 Sat 21:18]" :year-start 2018 :month-start 8 :day-start 4 :hour-start 21 :minute-start 18 :year-end 2018 :month-end 8 :day-end 4 :hour-end 21 :minute-end 18 :begin 46 :end 68 :post-blank 0)) :title "put into spacemacs file"))
```

What function will get me the parts in `CLOCK: [2018-08-04 Sat 21:16]--[2018-08-04 Sat 12:18] =>  0:02`?